# WCF and 127.0.0.1 vs localhost

Tags: wcf, localhost

Is there a different between using 127.0.0.1 vs localhost?

I ask this because I have noticed a difference when defining wcf connections.

```
<client>
  <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpNosecurity" contract="MyClass" name="MyName" behaviorConfiguration="megaGraphBehavior" address="net.tcp://localhost:8011/myname" />
</client>
```

In some environments i have noticed that a server suddenly starts throwing this error when using localhost and i can only make it work by using 127.0.0.1.

Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8011/myname. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.2341176. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8011.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8011

How can this be explained and should i always use 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 2):

Localhost by default references the IPv6 address on IPv6 enabled machines. Perhaps the server-side endpoint is only accessible via IPv4?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem today, and I just randomly solved it (I do not understand why these are here).

See this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

- See where I had **Auto-assign Port** checked and **Specific port 59816** was NOT checked?
- See where the message box shows `localhost:59816` and `127.0.0.1:59816`?

I fixed my issue by checking **Specific port 59816**.

This just might solve your problem, too.